# Is there a way to eliminate the extra screen after hitting "continue" in the Google Oauth flow?

Tags: oauth

I'm using the Google strategy in Devise to authenticate users through OAuth.  After clicking on a link in my app, the user is bounced to Google, where they select an account to use and hit continue.  However, currently they get another screen as below.

> The site www.site.com is requesting
>   access to your Google Account for the
>   product(s) listed below.
>
> Google Contacts

All I need is the auth part, and I'd like to eliminate this last screen from the flow.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you get that "requesting access" screen each time you log in via google?  Are you using openid or oauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required that they are brought to that screen and actually click OK.  Otherwise it wouldn't be hard too hard to trick people into giving you their auth cookies.  Also, if they aren't currently logged in they will be prompted to do that there.

Comment: That sounds right.  Hm, yeah I was thinking that there may be a way around it since I don't really need access to the Contacts, I just want a quick way to auth.  I think I could just use OpenID but that flow is confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem on one of my sites and I couldn't find anyway around having them click on the google link :-/  It does seem the most secure way to do it from Google's perspective though.